# Manage Wireguard VPN Clients

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, wireguard

I have a VPN app which uses OpenVPN/WireGuard protocol.
I have managed OpenVPN in a way that I use same config for all clients and my users connect very easily.

But for WireGuard this is not working, I have to make new config for every user, I have a script for that but the wg0.conf file gets too big making the server very slow. I added another script that removes older clients by checking if there handshake is more 5 minute. But these scripts overlap and mess up the config.
Can someone tell me any better way to do this? How can I manage WireGuard clients?
I have NginX installed through which I access the client creation scripts and the removing scripts is set in crontab which runs every 5 minutes.

Please suggest any alternate approach to manage clients that can be generated using API call and older clients are also removed.

Comment: Why would the wg-quick config file make the server slow? It is processed once, when the interface is set up, and maybe on changes. // You do not have to use wg-quick. It is but one possibility to set up the VPN interface.

Comment: @DanielB the server is being slowed down because the automated bash script that generates the key files, first looks in the wg0.conf file for used IPs and than creates a new config, adds in wg0.conf and returns it. When this happens 5-10 times per second it slows down.

Comment: That sounds, pardon me, absolutely insane and also totally unnecessary. Also entirely unrelated to _WireGuard_, which is just the VPN interface itself.

Comment: @DanielB please tell me what to do?
I need to connect multiple users to same server, but I cant keep on creating new users manually. What can be the alternate approach? To create new users automatically, add them and remove if they become inactive for too long

Comment: I’m not sure, sorry. I barely know your use case. If you want proper advice, you need to explain _everything_ from the beginning—not in the comments, but in your question. What are the numbers, where is your user data coming from, why do you need to remove them, …